# In query missing expressions of Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT b.*
FROM buses b,
     bus_stations bs,
     starts st,
     stops_at sa
WHERE st.station_no = ( SELECT station_id 
                        FROM bus_stations 
                        WHERE station_name = "golden mile_Regina"
                      )
  AND sa.station_no = ( SELECT station_id 
                        FROM bus_stations 
                        WHERE station_name = 'westmount_edmonton'
                      )
ORDER BY DATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use double quotes with strings - use single ones, i.e.

```
WHERE station_name = 'golden mile_Regina'
```

By the way, are you sure of spelling & letter size? Is it really mixed case, with underscores? Just asking.

Furthermore, you're ordering by `DATE` - that won't work either, you can't use DATE as a column name (unless you enclose it into double quotes, but I certainly wouldn't recommend that). Have a look at the following example (stupid, yes - setting date to be a number, but I used it just to emphasize that DATE can't be used as a column name):

```
SQL> create table test (date number);
create table test (date number)
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Once you fix that, you'll get unexpected result as there are 4 tables in the `FROM` clause, but they aren't joined with one another, so that will be a nice Cartesian product.